# How to track bones from one armature to another armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, tracking

I have this flexible part of this gearbox assembly and I need it to follow the motion of these bolts, specific bones are highlighted and the bolts are in red..[image] The bolts bounce up and down and sway side to side slightly. I need for the flexible part(metallic part) to follow perfectly with the bolt.
[image][image]
[image]

I tried adding a bone to the bolt, then copy rotation and location.  I got the bone moving along with the bolt but I was not able to copy the location and rotation of the specific bones on the flexible part.

Here's a video of the motion. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r-Predxy7Zb3qGpcL1xsmNvhLJQkUDr4/view?usp=sharing

Heres the file
[image]

Comment: how shall we help you without seeing any of your settings? so i recommend providing your blend file. Also little hint: you never ever checked an answer here as "correct answer" -> you can do this by pressing on the checkmark left of an answer. This might make the appearance that you are a bit unthankful. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npH7W.png if you press that button, the box in front would be green, like here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnjOv.png

Comment: What settings would you need to see? I cannot share the blend file.

Comment: you can always share a blend file. If it is too big, use any cloud service you want and share a link. If it has copyright - make a new file with a simplified setup and the same problem. Sorry - but you can always share a blend file. You want help from us - who help for free in our spare time, right? so if i were you i would make it as easy as possible for those who are willing to help. That's just my recommendation. Of course you don't have to...and hope for other to guess what your problem might be.

Comment: Why don't you make the control bone of the bendy bones not a child of the bolt bone? You can use the *Child Of* bone constraint since the bones are in different armature objects.